# Github markdown - image not rendering

Tags: image, github, markdown, mathjax

I struggle with rendering an image in a readme file on Github. As soon as I add mathjax after the image, the rendering doesn't work.

```
<br> We plot the results:  
![My Image](./demo_figure.png)  
<br>Some more text.. $$x+y=2$$
```

Preview:

[image]

If I remove the mathjax, everything works fine. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

Im unsure why this works but if you add a line break after your image link it renders.

```
<br> We plot the results:  
![My Image](./demo_figure.png)  

<br>Some more text.. $$x+y=2$$
```

Comment: weird and random, but it works! thank you!